# SQL Server : enabling xp_cmdshell remotely on a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd

I am logged on ServerA via HeidiSQL, this server has a link to ServerB and I have sysadmin privs on ServerB.

My question is: how can I enable `xp_cmdshell` on ServerB?

I know this syntax:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
RECONFIGURE

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1
RECONFIGURE
```

but this will run locally on ServerA, after some research I found the remote version of the RECONFIGURE command, which can be something like:

```
EXEC ('RECONFIGURE') AT "ServerB"
```

Now I am stuck at finding the remote version of the `sp_configure` commands

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run arbitrary batches with `exec(sql) at server`, so just

```
exec ('
EXEC sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'',1
RECONFIGURE
') at ServerB
```

Comment: Thanks a million! You're the best. :)